# How to run code after an imageView has appeared

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Is there some sort of UIImageViewDidAppear function in Swift, or similar functionality by a different name which I can override in my class inheriting UIImageView, that will not execute unless the UIImageView has actually appeared on the screen?

The init function occurs before my object appears and so I cannot use this.

Comment: try using viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: Can you use the normal view lifecycle? Essentially, what about `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: thats a view controller method not UIView's method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass UIImageView and override the method didMoveToSuperview:

```
class ImageView: UIImageView {
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        guard superview != nil else { return }
        print("put your code here")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution but you need to check the new `superview`. If it's `nil`, the image view has been removed. So you need to ensure `superview` isn't `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy are you sure? How can it be already moved to the superview if it is nil? BTW this is not `willMove(toSuperview:)` .

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I just verified it in a playground. When you call `removeFromSuperview`, the `didMoveToSuperview` will be called and at that point its `superview` is `nil`.

Comment: I have never tested this in a playground, but i have seen a situation in a real project that the superview is nil when this method gets called. Can you create a sample project in GitHub showing what you mean?

Comment: Your last comment is in agreement with my previous comment.

Comment: The OP wants to do something when the image view appears (not when it disappears). So in your `didMoveToSuperview` you should add `if superview != nil { // do stuff }`.

Comment: Note that in either case, this won't actually get called when the view appears on the screen.  Rather, it will get called when the view is added to the view hierarchy.  There are multiple reasons that might not appear at that point including it's scrolled off screen.